# How to display error lines from a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have these codes for uploading csv file. Also, I have put a GridView to display its contents. Now, what I want to do is to display error lines from the GridView, for example, if there are missing words in a particular column or row, I would want to display that that particular line is empty, and that the user has to reupload with that particular line updated. The thing is, I'm really new with this, I hope someone could help me! I do not know how to retrieve the error lines and display it on the website. These are my codes :

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileNameOnServer = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        string fileExt =
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);


        if (fileUpload.PostedFile != null && fileExt == ".csv")
        {

            try
            {

                //fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings + appDataPath + "\\" + strFileNameOnServer);
                fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded"));
                //string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
               // string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/MajorProject");
                Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                       "Content type: " +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Error saving <b>" + strFileNameOnServer + "</b><br>.  " + ex.Message;
            }
            BtnImport1.Visible = true;
            Cancel.Visible = true;
            fileUpload.Visible = false;
            btnUpload.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {

            Label1.Text = "Error - a file name must be specified/only csv files are allowed";
            return;

        }


        var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded"))  
          .Select(line => line.Split(','))    
          .Select(columns => new {GuestName = columns[0], Guest_ID = columns[1], IC_Number = columns[2]}); 
        myGridView.DataSource = data; 
        myGridView.DataBind(); 

        }
```

Do I have to add new items into my aspx file? Like a label to display the error lines? The contents of the csv file has Name, Ic Number and also House. If so, can anyone show me the codes to do this?

Comment: The fact that you are uploading a CSV file is not relevant to your question. Your question is how to indicate errors in a cell in a GridView.

Comment: @John Saunders, oh ya! Sorry I formatted the ques wrongly, will change it

Answer (score 0):

You could check for missing values on `GridView.RowDataBound` event for yours `myGridview`.

Example:

```
void myGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Check if any of the values of mygridview row cells are empty.
      if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "")
      {
           e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "ERROR: Guest name is empty!"
           e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "red");
      }
      if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "")
      {
           e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "ERROR: Guest Id is empty!"
           e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "red");
      }
      if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "")
      {
           e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "ERROR: Ic number is empty!"
           e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "red");
      }


    }

  }
```

Don't forget to declare it inside gridview properties:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridview" 
              runat="server" 
              OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try that when I get to my workplace in tmrw, thanks a lot!